# what does almost surely mean in this case

Tags: probability, almost-everywhere

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be some random variables and $\theta$ be a function of these random variables. I was asked to show that $\mathbb{P}(\theta=\hat{\theta}|X_1,...,X_n)=c$ almost surely. I am able to calculate the probability out explicitly, but I don't know what I am supposed to do with almost surely.

Comment: it means that the random variable defined by $Y:=\mathbb{P}(\theta =\hat \theta |X_1,\ldots ,X_n)$ is almost surely equal to $c$, that is, that there exists a set $A\subset \Omega $ such that $Y|_A\equiv c$ and $\mathbb{P}(A)=1$

Comment: So is $A$ some space for $X_1,...,X_n$?

Comment: no, $A$ is just an event of the underlying measure space, otherwise how it could be said that $\mathbb{P}(A)=1$?

Comment: So what is the definition of $\hat\theta$?

Comment: @orangecat To understand this, you need to look up the definition of conditional expectation. Conditional expectations are only defined almost surely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a particular realization $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ of $X_1\ldots, X_n$, the conditional probability $P(\theta = \hat \theta|x_1\ldots, x_n)$ is a specific number on $[0,1]$. But before we observe the $X_i$, the probability $P(\theta = \hat \theta|X_1\ldots, X_n)$ is a random variable! In other words, without seeing the $X_i$, we can ask about the distribution we expect $\theta$ to have after we see them and condition on them. For $P(\theta = \hat \theta|X_1\ldots, X_n)$ to equal $c$ "almost surely" is probabilist lingo meaning it equals $c$ with probability 1. In notation:
$$
P[P(\theta = \hat \theta|X_1\ldots, X_n) = c] = 1.
$$
The outer probability is a prior, conditioned on nothing. The inner probability is a random variable representing a probability conditioned on a piece of evidence which is determined randomly.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you understood wrongly what has been said to you about $\theta $. If $\theta $ is an unknown parameter, that defines a probability distribution, and we want to estimate it using a random sample $X_1,\ldots ,X_n$, then from this sample we construct an estimator for $\theta $, namely a function $\hat \theta :=f(X_1,\ldots ,X_n)$.

Then, by definition of conditional distribution, we have that
$$
\mathbb{P}(\hat \theta =\theta |X_1,\ldots ,X_n)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{\hat \theta =\theta \}}|X_1,\ldots ,X_n)=\mathbf{1}_{\{\hat \theta =\theta \}}
$$
as the function $\mathbf{1}_{\{\hat \theta =\theta \}}$ is $\sigma (X_1,\ldots ,X_n)$-measurable, where $\mathbf{1}_{G}$ is the characteristic function of the event $G$. Thus, as a characteristic function can just take the values zero or one, that $\mathbf{1}_{\{\hat \theta =\theta \}}=c$ almost surely means that $c\in\{0,1\}$, and consequently $\mathbb{P}(\hat \theta =\theta)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{\hat \theta =\theta \}})\in\{0,1\}$, that is, that the probability that $\hat \theta $ is equal to $\theta $ is zero or one.

Comment: Yup, just to add the almost-surely part comes from how conditional expectations are defined

Comment: @AndrewZhang in this case I don't think so, as if $Y$ is $\sigma (W)$-measurable the identity $\mathbb{E}(Y|W)=Y$ can be taken to be an exact equality, we don't need here the almost sure adjective.

Comment: To be pedantic, to make sense of the identity $E(Y\mid W) = Y$ one first needs to define $E(Y\mid W)$. If you agree that this is defined only almost surely, then $E(Y\mid W) = Y$ is not an equality.